# How do configure "when" conditional NLog rules?

Tags: nlog

I am trying to log conditional NLogs. I always pass a string (Rule1 or Rule2 in this example) that specifies what rule as the first part of a message.

My problem is that with the current rules below, both rules are being marked "true" and log files. I can't see how that is possible. I'm using the strings of "Rule1" and "Rule2" for this example, but the actual strings passed are completely different (not the same word with a different number).

Example messages that are getting passed to be logged are...

Ex1: `${message} = "Rule1,Information about the rule,foo`

Ex2: `${message} = "Rule2,Information about the other rule,bar`

Here are my example targets

```xml
<!-- language: config -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="false"
  internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log"
  keepVariablesOnReload="true">

  <variable name="dir_Logging" value="C:/<myPath>"/>
  <variable name="dir_Archive_Rule1" value="${dir_Logging}/Log Archives/Rule1/${shortdate}"/>
  <variable name="dir_Archive_Rule2" value="${dir_Logging}/Log Archives/Rule2/${shortdate}"/>
  <variable name="varRule1" value="Rule1"/>
  <variable name="varRule2" value="Rule2"/>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="rule1Logs"
      archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
      archiveNumbering="Date"
      archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"
      fileName="${dir_Logging}/Logs - Rule1.csv"
      archiveFileName="${dir_Archive_Rule1}/Logs - Rule1.{#}.csv">
        <layout xsi:type="SimpleLayout"
          text="&quot;${date:format= yyyy/MM/dd}&quot;,&quot;${date:format= HH\:mm\:ss.fff}&quot;,${message}"/>
    </target>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="rule2Logs"
      archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
      archiveNumbering="Date"
      archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"
      fileName="${dir_Logging}/Logs - Rule2.csv"
      archiveFileName="${dir_Archive_Rule2}/Logs - Rule2.{#}.csv">
        <layout xsi:type="SimpleLayout"
          text="&quot;${date:format= yyyy/MM/dd}&quot;,&quot;${date:format= HH\:mm\:ss.fff}&quot;,${message}"/>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" level="Info" writeTo="rule1Logs">
      <filters>
        <when condition="starts-with('${message}','${varRule1}')" action="Log"/>
      </filters>
    </logger>
    <logger name="*" level="Info" writeTo="rule2logs">
      <filters>
        <when condition="starts-with('${message}','${varRule2}')" action="Log"/>
      </filters>
    </logger>
  </rules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default of the filter is "neutral", so if it won't match your filter, it get logged.

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2151) and will be addressed in NLog 4.6 ([See code change in NLog 4.6](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2848))

For now you need to:

1. inverse the condition and `action=ignore`
2. OR, add a 2nd filter that ignores all

Comment: I got it working. I hadn't realized I was passing quotes in the message. Adding &quote; before and after worked.